# pass Polymer data binding through a Javascript function

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm using Polymer and Dart to produce a list of point coordinates. It renders a list of points in html. Nevertheless I want to convert the points from one coordinate system to another using a javascript function.

In HTML dart-polymer:

```
<template repeat="{{ p in grid_points }}">
    <core-item>{{ p }}</core-item>
</template>
```

The javascript I found in a library:

```
grid_to_geodetic(x, y);
```

grid_points is a List of Points. How can I pass p.x and p.y through the js function and get the result rendered in place of p in the HTML template?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [expression filter](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filters) for that:

```
<template repeat="{{ p in grid_points }}">
    <core-item>{{ p | grid_to_geodetic }}</core-item>
</template>
...
<script>
  Polymer('your-element', {
    grid_to_geodetic: function(point){
       return point.x + point.y;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Filter takes one value and returns one, if you need to convert x and y separately you have to use an constant parameter to indicate which part of the point you want to convert, something like

```
<template repeat="{{ p in grid_points }}">
    <core-item>{{ p | grid_to_geodetic(1) }}</core-item>
    <core-item>{{ p | grid_to_geodetic(2) }}</core-item>
</template>
...
<script>
  Polymer('your-element', {
    grid_to_geodetic: function(point, part){
       if(part == 1) return point.x;
       else return point.y;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I assume you mean 'core-item' where you put 'your-element'?.

In any case I have tried what you said but get an error:

    Polymer('core-item', {
     rt90_to_wgs84: function (point) {
      return point.x + point.y;
     }
    });

Exception: Error evaluating expression '(p | rt90_to_wgs84)': Class 'TrainList' has no instance getter 'rt90_to_wgs84'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'rt90_to_wgs84'
Receiver: Instance of 'TrainList'
Arguments: []

It's as if it were trying to use the Dart class, rather than a create a new Javascript function, which could eventually call grid_to_geodetic()

Comment: No, I meant "your-element". I assumed that the template is part of your custom component... thats how it works in custom component created in pure polymer, I don't use Dart myself so I dont know how it changes things, sorry. Hmm, you could actually try to use plain old JS function and skip the Polumer('your-element'... stuff?

Comment: Yes, I tried just putting the JS function in the filter expression to no avail. A reference to a Dart method prints something:

<core-item>{{ p | rt90_to_wgs84 }}</core-item>

    rt90_to_wgs84(p) {
      print(p.toString());
    }

But can't get it to call JS. I have tried to look at JsFunction and JsObject but just cannot figure it out. The function is just a plain global funcion in the JS file. I don't know what JsFunction.withThis() is for, and JsObject.callMethod? I have no object or method, just that global function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Dart so can't help with this... looks like my answer is of no help, i'll delete it a bit later.

Comment: err, now in your solution You refer to my post so perhaps I should keep it :) Anyway, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to invoke it thanks to some ideas from ain:

So with the expression filter you are telling the template to invoke a *Dart* function:

```
<template repeat="{{ p in start_points }}">
    <core-item>{{ p | rt90_to_wgs84 }}</core-item>
</template>
```

Then in the Dart backing class you add a function with the same name as in the filter and you call a global js function with `context.callMethod('funcion_name', [args_list]);`:

```
rt90_to_wgs84(p) {
  return context.callMethod('grid_to_geodetic', [p.x, p.y]);
}
```